# How to create new slide item in owl carousel dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I want to create owl item slides dynamically on the basis of conditions. Such as

```
if(i=1 && i<=4)
{

//generate new item slide (owl carousel)
}
else if(i>=4 && i<=8)
{

//Generate second slide
}
```

I am creating the slide item manually, i want to make them dynamically on the basis of condition in jquery. Suppose the first condition met, create new slide item dynamically, if second condition met, create new slide dynamically. I am new at jquery

Ps:- slide should create dynamically with the help of jquery .

Here is slider code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="myjs2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <style>
    body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
    padding:15px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}

    </style>

   
    <title>yes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">



 <div class="item">
 first slide
  </div>
  <div class="item">
 second slide
  </div>
  <div class="item">
 Third slide
  </div>
</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

     navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons

     slideSpeed : 300,
     paginationSpeed : 400,

     items : 1, 
     itemsDesktop : false,
     itemsDesktopSmall : false,
     itemsTablet: false,
     itemsMobile : false

 });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just add the additional Div from the JS dynamically

Comment: not getting, how to do this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="myjs2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <style>
    body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
    padding:15px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}

    </style>


    <title>yes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"> 1 slide  </div>
    <div class="item"> 2 slide </div>
    <div class="item"> 3 slide  </div>
</div>
<button id="addCarous"> Add Carousel</button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

     navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons

     slideSpeed : 300,
     paginationSpeed : 400,

     items : 1, 
     itemsDesktop : false,
     itemsDesktopSmall : false,
     itemsTablet: false,
     itemsMobile : false

 });
$("#addCarous").click(function(e){
debugger;
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("item").length +1;
    e.preventDefault(); //-- prevent form submit
    $('#owl-demo').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="item"> '+number+' slide </div>'])
        .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is an optional parameter. It specifies the function that returns the content to insert. Index: It returns the index position of the element in the set. HTML: It returns the current HTML of the selected element. It's just like appending the tag inside the (carousel).

> $("#id").trigger('add.owl.carousel',[])

Events are provided by Owl Carousel in strategic code locations. This gives you the ability to listen for any changes and perform your own actions.
You could also trigger events by yourself to control Owl Carousel

> initialize.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onInitialize  When
>   the plugin initializes.
>
> initialized.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onInitialized 
>   When the plugin has initialized.
>
> resize.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onResize  When the
>   plugin gets resized.
>
> resized.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onResized  When the
>   plugin has resized.
>
> refresh.owl.carousel Type: attachable, cancelable, triggerable 
>   Callback: onRefresh  Parameter: [event, speed]  When the internal
>   state of the plugin needs update.
>
> refreshed.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onRefreshed  When
>   the internal state of the plugin has updated.
>
> drag.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onDrag  When the
>   dragging of an item is started.
>
> dragged.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onDragged  When the
>   dragging of an item has finished.
>
> translate.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onTranslate  When
>   the translation of the stage starts.
>
> translated.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onTranslated  When
>   the translation of the stage has finished.
>
> change.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onChange  Parameter:
>   property  When a property is going to change its value.
>
> changed.owl.carousel Type: attachable  Callback: onChanged  Parameter:
>   property  When a property has changed its value.
>
> next.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: [speed]  Goes to next
>   item.
>
> prev.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: [speed]  Goes to
>   previous item.
>
> to.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: [position, speed]  Goes
>   to position.
>
> destroy.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Destroys carousel.
>
> replace.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: data  Removes
>   current content and add a new one passed in the parameter.
>
> add.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: [data, position]  Adds
>   a new item on a given position.
>
> remove.owl.carousel Type: triggerable  Parameter: position  Removes an
>   item from a given position.

To use Owl Carousel, you’ll need to make sure both the Owl and jQuery 1.7 or higher scripts are included.You don't need any special markup. All you need is to wrap your divs(owl works with any type element) inside the container element . Class "owl-carousel" is mandatory to apply proper styles that come from owl.carousel.css file.

http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the carousel store the carousel object in a variable for future use.

```js
var $owl = $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed: 300,
  paginationSpeed: 400,
  items: 1,
  itemsDesktop: false,
  itemsDesktopSmall: false,
  itemsTablet: false,
  itemsMobile: false,
});
```

Owl carousel provides the `refresh.owl.carousel` event for updating the carousel state when you modify the slides.

**Example:**

```js
if ((i = 1 && i <= 4)) {
  $("#owl-demo").append('<div class="item">New slide</div>');
} else if (i >= 4 && i <= 8) {
  $("#owl-demo").append('<div class="item">New slide 2</div>');
}

// We are refreshing the carousel state to update new slide
$owl.trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
```

You can find all the supported options [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#refresh-owl-carousel)

Comment: Got it .Thanks a lot