# How to apped dynamic data into owl carousel slide using ajax call in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Owl carousel is not working after appending dynamic data.

I want to load my owl-carouse modal with dynamic content by onclick event via ajax call. Here is the div where I want to append success respoonse data.

```
     <div class="item">
       <div class="thumbnail-item">
          <div class="thumbnail-img-box2">
            <img src="{{ asset('frontend/asset/images/update-img/Group 1 10 (1).png') }}" alt="image">
         </div>
             <h6>Heading</h6>
      </div>
  </div>
```

In ajax success respone, I append this

```
      $('.append-div').append(`
         <div class="item">
           <div class="thumbnail-item">
              <div class="thumbnail-img-box2">
                 <img src="{{ asset('frontend/asset/images/update-img/Group 1 10 (1).png') }}"alt="image">
              </div>
            <h6>SPG-28</h6>
         </div>
     </div>
  `);
```

Data is appended successfully, but the problem is owl-carousel is not working also it append one after one, not append as slide.

How to load daynamic content on owl-carousel?

Comment: Notice that you are not closing the IMG tag when you are appending the item on success response.
btw, do you get any error on the console?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error, my response data is prefectly loaded into owl carousel modal, but the carousel is not working & all data is shown one after one, I want to show them slide by slide

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022159/how-to-create-new-slide-item-in-owl-carousel-dynamically) should be helpful.

Comment: I checked that already but my problem isn't solved yet

Comment: Can you show working code with that behaviour ?

Comment: problem has solved